# htaccess using RewriteRule and RewriteCond to redirect specific url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have to redirect (301) from

http://domain/index.php to 
http://domain/

I've done it with following rules:

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

Ok. it works, BUT I do NOT want to allow redirect from urls like:

http://domain/**asd**/index.php

I've tried to change condition like:

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/index.php

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/index.php

but no success.

So, how to redirect ONLY from http://domain/index.php to http://domain/

ps: I do not want to use REDIRECT command

Comment: RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/index.php

Comment: Why don't you simply use apache's `DirectoryIndex` directive? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html

Comment: Unamata Sanatarai - like I wrote, it not work

Comment: arkascha - I didn't know that, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This work exactly like I expected ! Thank very much.

Comment: Offcourse I had to put the my RewriteCond before it.

Comment: You don't need it.

Comment: I'just checked again. And if I do not put RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php in line before it redirects all incomin requests. So I need add it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R]
```

Comment: @Kriss The solution I posted works fine for me. Its same as the accepted answer. Not sure why you are saying "its not working" .

Comment: I copy and past it into my .htaccess and it doesn't do what I expected, so as I wrote, "not work for me". I belive it can work in other .htaccess. My .htaccess is file from PrestaShop. Maybe this is the reason.